# how to determine value of the d in rabin karp

Tags: algorithm, search

In rabin karp algorithm `d` is the number of elements in the Alphabet.
for example;

```
text = a a c b a d
```

in here `d` is 4.

If user can enter the text and pattern, in that case how can we assign value to `d`.
In many places I have seen `d=256`. is this a convention?

Comment: well, char in C is 8 bits, so there are 2^8 = 256 possible characters..

Comment: @Haile- even though  the text and pattern does not have all the characters, using 256 will not make any bad effect?

Comment: It depends on how the value of d is used, doesn't it? There's not a single implementation of rabin karp..